# Update ios app data in foreground and background

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm finding the best way to update an iOS app data for both foreground and background states. The app is developed using Xamarin.
These are my requirements:
1)Every 15 minutes I need to call a web api and check if there is new data. 
2)If there's new data, I need to save it to sqlite db and show a local notification after a short amount of time.
This should work for both foreground and background states.

One solution I'm thinking is to use a timer to update data when app is in foreground, then if app goes in background, since timer in background is not supported, I'll stop the timer and use background fetch.

My concern is if there's a better solution or way to do this.

Comment: You can use background fetch but it won't be every 15 minutes. If you must update every 15 minutes then you need a server side push

Comment: Hi Paulw, in my case, in background state, updates don't have to occur exactly every 15 minutes

Comment: Then background fetch is probably simplest